# How will I handle a unexpected native android screen using appium

Tags: android, appium

I am running an automation for an app and with the latest app version , I am seeing survey page which appears on clicking the back button certain number of times.

How would I handle this scenario. Is there any appium API which helps me to check if current screen displayed is the page I want?

Comment: why don't you verify the element on the page based on the requirements. This way you can verify if correct page is displayed.

Comment: You should verify survey page after clicking on back button if that present then click handle it or continue next steps.

Comment: @Gaurav Checking the element on the page everytime I press the back button is not a feasible options with the certain timeout set. I mean what if the page didn't appear, the appium would wait for certain amount of time.
What if I have to press the back button 20 times before survey page has to come. Then wait time get added up 19 times before it find successfully.
My question was, is there any dynamic way to do this?